# How to make a treeview uncollapsable?

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

Using the TreeView control in WinForms, is there a property that can be set to hide the collapse-node icons for each node?

Also, how do I permanently expand all nodes in the TreeView?

Comment: Hi @Blaxx just to make sure, is this a asp.net TreeView or winforms TreeView?

Comment: No worries, so just to make sure; so on a webpage (asp.net) or winforms (i.e. .net on the desktop) ?

Comment: ah, this is what you mean, winforms

Comment: Hi @Blaxx I'm not sure what you mean by the "forbid expand-nodes"? And "I want the nodes to be visible all the time."? Do you mean that you want the top level nodes to be visible, but all the subnodes to be hidden and not viewable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to handle the `OnBeforeExpand` event and set `Cancel` to `true`.

```
private void OnBeforeExpand(TreeViewCancelEventArgs e)
{
   e.Cancel = true;
}
```

Keep in mind that this would prevent **any** tree node from expanding.

If you want to hide the "+/-" symbols, you should set the `ShowPlusMinus` property to `false`.

Answer (score 2):

You could try handling the `BeforeCollapse` event and setting the `e.Cancel = true`, always.

Answer (score 1):

You can intercept the [`TreeView.BeforeCollapse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.beforecollapse%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) event

```
private void YourBeforeCollapseEventHandler(object sender, TreeViewCancelEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```