# How to stop automatically collapsing treeview structure when click on a childnode asp.net Visual studio 2008

Tags: asp.net, c#-3.0

I am using ASP.NET with C# 3.5 and Visual Studio 2008. I am using a Master page and content pages. I have a treeview menu in the master page and when a user selects any menu item I redirect to that content page.

My problem is that after a user navigates to the content page all the treenodes refresh and the structure is collapsed. I want the selected treenode to stay expanded.
Can anybody help me to solve this problem??

At first my treeview works properly.But some nodes in tree view doesn't redirected to forms means first time every nodes goes to corresponding forms.but for d second time its not getting.when am set AutoEventWireup="false" then that problem solved.evrynodes works proeperly.and nw problem arises.that is the nodes in treeview are collapsing.when we select parent child,to sub,then sub when we click on a node, the tree view automatically comes back to parent node.

How to implement that?

Below am attaching my code:

MasterPage.master:

```
<asp:TreeView runat="server" ID="treeModule"   
BorderColor="White" Height="1310px"  
                                      OnSelectedNodeChanged="treeModule_SelectedNodeChanged" 
OnTreeNodeExpanded ="treeModule_TreeNodeExpanded"
style= "margin-top: 0px" BackColor="#336699" BorderStyle="Inset" 
Font-Names="Arial" ForeColor="Black" ImageSet="Contacts" 
NodeIndent="10" ExpandDepth="0"  >
```

At Masterpage.master.cs:

```
 protected void treeModule_SelectedNodeChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


         if (treeModule.SelectedNode.Text == "User")
        {
            Session["SaveEditMode"] = "Save";
            Session["InboxMode"] = "N";

            Response.Redirect("~/UserCreation.aspx");
        }
         #region SubContrctModule

         if (treeModule.SelectedNode.Text == "WorkOrder Advance Report")
         {
             Session["SaveEditMode"] = "Save";
             Session["InboxMode"] = "N";

             Response.Redirect("~/SubContract/Reports/AdvanceRequestReport.aspx");
         }
         if (treeModule.SelectedNode.Text == "Sub Contractor Master")
         {
             Session["SaveEditMode"] = "Save";
             Session["InboxMode"] = "N";

             Response.Redirect("~/SubContract/SubContractorMaster.aspx");
         }
         if (treeModule.SelectedNode.Text == "Work Category Settings")
         {
             Session["SaveEditMode"] = "Save";
             Session["InboxMode"] = "N";

             Response.Redirect("~/SubContract/WorkCategoryMaster.aspx");
         }
         if (treeModule.SelectedNode.Text == "Work Type Settings")
         {
             Session["SaveEditMode"] = "Save";
             Session["InboxMode"] = "N";

             Response.Redirect("~/SubContract/WorkTypeMaster.aspx");
         }
         if (treeModule.SelectedNode.Text == "Work Order Settings")
         {
             Session["SaveEditMode"] = "Save";
             Session["InboxMode"] = "N";
             Response.Redirect("~/SubContract/WorkOrderMaster.aspx");
         }
         if (treeModule.SelectedNode.Text == "Advance Request")
         {
             Session["SaveEditMode"] = "Save";
             Session["InboxMode"] = "N";

             Response.Redirect("~/SubContract/AdvanceRequest.aspx");
         }
         if (treeModule.SelectedNode.Text == "Advance Payment")
         {
             Session["SaveEditMode"] = "Save";
             Session["InboxMode"] = "N";

             Response.Redirect("~/SubContract/AdavancePayment.aspx");
         }
         if (treeModule.SelectedNode.Text == "Billing Master")
         {
             Session["SaveEditMode"] = "Save";
             Session["InboxMode"] = "N";

             Response.Redirect("~/SubContract/BillingMaster.aspx");
         }


         if (treeModule.SelectedNode.Text == "Rating Percentage Setting")
        {
            Session["SaveEditMode"] = "Save";
            Session["InboxMode"] = "N";

            Response.Redirect("~/Material Module/ISO/ISORatingPercentageMaster.aspx");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit difficult without seeing any code, but I believe your problem is in the asp:TreeView tag/server control. Check if you have the attribute 'ExpandDepth' set to any value. I would remove it completely, or set it to 'FullyExpand'.

Comment: Please, check this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7066868/how-to-make-a-treeview-unexpandable)

Comment: Again another problem is there.Am using visual studio 2008 in that boforecollapse event i didn't get.How i can access before collapse event of treeview in visual studio 2008????

Answer (score 1):

Say PopulateTree  is your function name by which you are population the tree view. So put the PopulateTree function inside !isPostback.

```
if (!IsPostBack)
   {
     PopulateTree();

   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to expand the node based on the URL of the new page

http://forums.asp.net/t/1766332.aspx/1